# How to configure osquery with auditd

Tags: linux, security, logging, auditd

Who has expertise on how to work with osquery (or maybe you solved this problem):

1. Based on articles like this one - https://blog.palantir.com/auditing-with-osquery-part-two-configuration-and-implementation-87a8bba0ef48 I understand osquery can be used in conjunction with auditd rules in auditd/audit.rules. However, when I try to change in osquery.flags
   --audit_allow_config=false to use my rules, the process_events stop coming at all, although with the --debug option their registration is visible
2. Is it possible to log osquery all syscalls like auditd? So far only execve is visible in process_events

I use config and flags file from https://github.com/palantir/osquery-configuration/tree/master/Classic/Servers/Linux

Thank you in advance!